# html5 in php hosting?

Tags: php, html, web-hosting

I am software engineering student.
I want to setup a website using html5 and css3. I looked up various web hosting options. I want to use hosting that provides php and mysql, so that I can practice those as well. 
Will a hosting based on php and mysql provide support for html5 and css3? If yes, will the html5 code just be inserted into pages that are php extension?

I am very new to this, can some one please help.

Thanks.

Comment: This question doesn't deserve the downvotes or to be closed. It's a legitimate confusion for a new programmer to web development.

Comment: "HTML5 support" can mean various things. The new page markup is mostly independent from the hosting company (it could be complicated if `mod_tidy` was installed, but highly uncommon). If you were referring to other "HTML5 technologies" like Websockets (did you?), then a shared hosting server is likely unsuitable.

Comment: HTML and CSS are the basic part of any web application. There are configuration like server settings, virtual host and etc which needs to be configured properly. If you don't know much about hosting you can try managed hosting like Cloudways for free

Answer (score 10):

HTML and CSS of **ANY** version are just plain text. Any language that can generate/consume plain text can work with either of them. You can do an entire dynamic website using bash scripts or a compiled C program if you wish. PHP just happens to be a bit more efficient at text handling than either of those. But it's not the only thing that can generate a page.

HTML is not "code". It's "markup", same for CSS.

Answer (score 9):

Right, HTML5 and CSS3 are not handled by your host, they are rendered on the client side, so every host allows you to use them. You can write HTML5 and CSS3 into PHP files directly and they will be rendered as if they were HTML files, with the advantage of being able to use PHP on those pages.

When buying servers you are buying space on the company's computers and for them to maintain your files, not deal with client-side rendering.

Answer (score 5):

CSS3 and HTML5 Depends on the User's (your client's) browser. It has nothing to do with the server you page is on.

Answer (score 4):

HTML5 and CSS3 are browser based technologies, so your hosting provider doesn't matter. Only which browser a user has matters as to whether those technologies are supported.

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 and CSS 3 are indeed languages that are processed by a web browser (client side), therefore the hosting server (server side) doesn't render, parse, or execute any kind of HTML 5 or CSS 3 code.  But other posters have already mentioned this.

If you are a new web programmer, I submit this concept to you: "graceful degradation".  Since as a web programmer you have zero control over what kind of browser your end user uses, it is beneficial to plan your shots.  HTML 5 and CSS 3 are emerging technologies that have varied levels of support across the various web browsers available to the public.  Graceful Degradation means that you want to use HTML 5/CSS 3 technologies, and you implement them but you leave methods/means for your users to still interact with your website if those technologies are not supported by the browser they are using.

Here are some links to articles that might be useful to you in learning about how to make your page/website perform Graceful Degradation:

[Article 1](http://webtips.dan.info/graceful.html),

[Article 2](http://www.anybrowser.org/campaign/abdesign.html),

[Article 3](http://webdesign.about.com/od/webdesignglossary/g/graceful-degradation.htm)

Alternatively there is another idea that also corresponds to this concept, known as "Progressive Enhancement".  I'm just going to quote the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement):

> In Progressive Enhancement (PE) the strategy is deliberately reversed: a basic markup document is created, geared towards the lowest common denominator of browser software functionality, and then the designer adds in functionality or enhancements to the presentation and behavior of the page, using modern technologies such as Cascading Style Sheets or JavaScript (or other advanced technologies, such as Flash or Java applets or SVG, etc.) All such enhancements are externally linked, preventing data unusable by certain browsers from being unnecessarily downloaded.

Good luck!

H